# Access denied for user 'totallig_root'@'197.210.64.73' (using password: YES) when conneting to online database from localhost

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to access my online database from localhost but gives the mentioned error. I tested it online and it worked.

Under **Databases**, I have added my computer ip address to **Remote MySQL**.

> Access denied for user 'totallig_root'@'197.210.64.73' (using
>   password: YES)

my connection strings

```
$host = 'totallightschools.com:3306';
$user = '******';
$pass = '******';
$db = '******';

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an MySQL user in your MySQL instance, with the name `totallig_root` and given password, which is allowed to connect from your host (`197.210.64.73`) you should be able to connect with this function:

```
mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db,$port);
```

So you have to specify the port (if it's not the default port) in a seperate argument. The user in your MySQL instance should look something like this: `totallig_root@197.210.64.73` or `totallig_root@%` (to allow to connect from all hosts)

Source: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysqli-connect.php